# How to find the nearby genes from differentially expressed locus

Tags: linux, genomicranges

I am interesting in to find out the nearby gene of differentially expressed locus from bedtools. 1000 upstream and downstream genes
I have a list of differentially expressed locus in .xlsx format.
Now I want to know that how can I extract the gene those are the surroundings of locus and how can I see the locus region??
Can anyone give their suggestion??
suggestions really required.

Comment: You will have to be more specific. What have you already tried yourself? SO is not a free coding service. Are you trying to extract all the genes within a 1000 basepair range of your differentially expressed locus?

Comment: yes..you are getting absolutely right. Could you please guide on this?

Comment: What have you already tried yourself?